# Extending a smooth map

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

When can I extend a smooth map $f:\mathbb{R^2}-\lbrace 0 \rbrace \to S^1$ to a smooth map $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R^2} \to S^1$.  For instance, consider $g(x,y)=(x,y)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?  Am I able to extend that to a smooth map $g$?  My end goal is having the smooth map from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $S^1$.  It can be any map, this is just how I am trying to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately your map $g$ won't extend at the origin : $g$ is clearly not bounded around $(0,0)$.
If you want a smooth map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $S^1$ why don't you consider a map of the form $(x,y)\mapsto e^{i\theta(x,y)}$ with a "nice" $\theta$ ?

Comment: @Bebop: of course the map is bounded near zero: it takes values in $S^1$.

Comment: Yes of course, I don't know why I wrote "bounded" instead of "continuous". Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a specific smooth function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $S^1$ you can use for example : 
$$f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow S^1$$
$$f(x,y)=(\sin x, \cos x)$$
There are some other ways to construct smooth maps between manifolds. One way is to use the so called **bump functions**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

These functions are smooth and have a compact support. If you extend the function to be zero in the rest of the manifold and nonzero inside its compact support you have a smooth map, from the manifold to $\mathbb R$ in this case.

Comment: What you wrote down is not a function taking values in $S^1$.

Comment: yeah I fixed it now

Comment: $@$Dimitris: Okay, that's a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $S^1$.  So is $f(x,y) = 1$.  The OP was asking about extending a given function smoothly to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Does your answer address this?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark  "My end goal is having the smooth map from R2 to S1. It can be any map, this is just how I am trying to do it. "

What I make out from this is that any smooth map is required.

Comment: $@$Dimitris: What do you make of the OP's first sentence then?

Comment: You are both right I essentially had two questions: I was considering both extending smooth maps to the form I wanted and smooth maps in general of the form I wanted.  @PeteL.Clark gave a good answer discussing the general extension and Dimitris gave a good answer for general construction of smooth maps.  Thank you both :)

Comment: @Leo: If in fact you have two distinct questions, could you please edit your post to make this more clear?

Answer (score 4):

Of course a necessary condition is that $f$ extend *continuously* to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Your map does not extend continuously: it takes a constant nonzero value along each ray through the origin, and this value is different for different rays, so $\lim_{P \rightarrow 0} f(P)$ does not exist.

Here is a criterion for continuous extension over a point:

$\bullet$ Theorem: Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.  Then $f$ extends continuously to $0$ iff it is uniformly continuous on each bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$.

See $\S$ 10.11 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf) for a proof, especially Corollary 10.48.  The text takes $n = 1$ but the arguments work verbatim in the general case.

This adapts immediately to continuity of vector-valued functions, because a function $f = (f_1,\ldots,f_m): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous iff each of its coordinate functions $f_i: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

It is harder to give sufficient conditions for differentiability.  I can think of one in one variable:

> Theorem: Let $I$ be an open interval, let $a \in I$, and let $f: I \setminus \{a\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Suppose:
> (i) $f$ extends continuously to $a$.
> (ii) $f$ is differentiable at each $x \in I \setminus \{a\}$, and
> (iii) $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f'(x) = L$ exists.
> Then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a) = L$.

I learned this result from Spivak's *Calculus*.  A proof is given in $\S$ 5.5.5 [*loc. cit.*](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf).

Off the top of my head, I'm not sure whether this result extends to differentiable functions of several variables.  (Someone around here must know -- please tell me.)