# Extending smooth maps from the punctured disk

Tags: smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

Suppose that I have a smooth map of manifolds $f: M^n \rightarrow D^2\backslash 0$ and $f$ is a submersion, i.e. a fiber bundle over $D^2 \backslash 0$. When is it possible to find another smooth map of manifolds $g: N^n \rightarrow D^2$ such that $M^n \subset N^n$ and $g$ extends $f$? Ideally, I would also want that $N^n \backslash M^n$ has codimension 1 in $N^n$.

Note that I am allowed to pick $N^n$, unlike in the following post [Extending a smooth map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375655/extending-a-smooth-map) 
where $N^n$ is prescribed a priori.

If I don't care that $N$ and $g$ are smooth, then this is always possible. Just take the one point compactification $\hat{M}$ of $M$ and extend the map $f$ continuously to compactification.

Comment: First, not every submersion is a fiber bundle, so you probably want your maps to be surjective and proper. Also, the one-point compactification does not provide a continuous extension, as you can already see from the example where $M^n = D^2 \setminus 0$ and $f$ is the identity. By the way, is it supposed to be $D^n$ or $D^2$ for the extension?

Comment: Thanks! But why does the one-point-compactification not work? If its $D^2 \backslash 0$, then the compactification is $D^2$ which maps by the identity to $D^2$.

Comment: This is true if you think of $D^2$ as the closed disk (which is a manifold with boundary), but not if you take it as the open disk, in which case the one-point compactification would be a pinched torus, not the closed disk.